# what is dart (?. ) notation refer to?

Tags: flutter, dart

as you maybe seen before in Effective Dart: Usage

(https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage)
you see :

```
optionalThing?.isEnabled ?? false;
```

I know `val??other` is an alternative of `val == null ? other : val`

but I don't understand what is `?.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?.` operator is part of the `null-aware` operators. This is used in the following context:

```
if(object != null)
{
    object.method1();
}
```

The above can be written as `object?.method1();`

So a code `bool isEnabled = optionalThing?.isEnabled ?? false;` will translate to following:

```
bool isEnabled;
if(optionalThing != null)
   isEnabled = optionalThing.isEnabled;
else
   isEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

That question mark is for optionals. You can find this in swift, Kotlin and typescript as well.

Following your example `optionalThing?.isEnabled` is the same as:

```
optionalThing == null ? null : optionalThing.isEnabled;
```

This lets you call a method or property of an object without having to check whether the object is null. In case the object is null it would return null instead of crashing and that property or method would not be called.